# Moving files from D drive to E drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I am going to move the whole files in my **D** drive to the **E** drive (win10 system). I have downloaded many applications to the **D** drive, such as python, virtualBox etc. Some applications had to be installed and then they required adding environment variables (for instance for java and python). Therefore many addresses within the **D** drive are referenced to in different applications and system settings. I want to  move all files to **E** then change **E**'s name to **D**. The previous space of the **D** drive will be merged to the **C** drive. I don't know whether it works or if it will create some problems. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Copy file from `D:` to `E:` is one thing and migrating applications installed on drive `D:` to drive `E:` it's another. If the application MUST not be reinstalled try to install a new instance on volume `E:` and adapt the old configurations to the new instance and uninstall the old version. Otherwise Windows applications create records in registry. If you simple move the app from `D:` to `E:` and change the `PATH` it can easily happen that the application will not work. Consider this.

Comment: Reading it fully, it will be fine. Perhaps some temporary hiccups if there autostart apps or services.

Comment: It would be easier to clone D to E using clonezilla or some other drive cloning software. That is, so long as you're happy with the filesystem also being cloned. The advantage of doing it this way is you will have an exact replica of the drive - block for block. So you are less likely to encounter issues that might otherwise have come from manually copying the data yourself (missing hidden files/folders etc..). If you wish to use a different filesystem on the new drive then this wont work, because the filesystem is also cloned.

Comment: One thing to add here if you go down the cloning route.. your new drive has to be the same size or bigger than your old drive. If bigger, the newly cloned drive will come out looking the same size as the old drive.. this can be easily changed inside disk management. You simply shrink the drive partition by 1000 bytes which will allow windows to calculate the remaining free space on the drive, and then you can extend the partition into the remaining free space afterwards allowing you to make use of the drive full capacity.

Comment: ysmpreme, the title of your posting is misleading. It suggests it is just about copying files and will steer helpful people away from your post. I reworked your posting. It is a good idea to invest two minutes to reread one own posting and correct obvious mistakes. I left the change of title for you...